# Eclipse unable to locate Java in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, payara

While I am trying to install the Payara server on my Ubuntu machine after putting the path of the Payara/glassfish server when I try to put the java  location whatever i give as path is considered as error. I use Oracle java 10 and as I put the value "/usr/lib/java/jdk-10.0.1/" it says its not a jdk. Path for Java 10 has been properly set in ~/.bashrc as

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk-10.0.1/
export PATH="$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Why is this behaving in this way? Can anybody suggest me a way out.

Comment: I'd bet an `echo $PATH` should reveal the problem (nb usually there should be no need to explicitly change PATH unless you have multiple versions of Java installed)

Comment: Please, if a response is correct and solved your problem accept the response using the 'V' button, otherwise write a comment under the answer in order to give more detail about the question

Answer (score 1):

try `export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin`

Comment: Made tthe changes. But without the changes I could easily compile and run a Java program. My problem is when I try to install Payara server in eclipse its showing me error as i type the path /usr/lib/java/jdk-10

Comment: as "JDK is required rather than JRE". If the bin folder is added then the error becomes "No Jav installation found in the folder."

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. Payara can't find JAVA_HOME or the entire system? If you type in your console `java --version` and the result is something like `java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)` Java is correctly configured in the system

Comment: I am using Oracle JDK 10. When I am typing the path for jdk while creating a new instance of Payara server in Eclipse, whatever I put its giving me an error. But typing java -version is correctly showing the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell is interpreting `JAVA_HOME` as string, you forgot a `$` before `JAVA_HOME` in the `export PATH` line to make it interpret as a **variable**.